# Why doesn't Naruto possess any of his clan's specific jutsu?

Tags: naruto

Neji, Hinata, Shino, Kiba, Sasuke, Choji, Shikamaru and Ino all have their clans' Kekkai Genkai, e.g. Shikamaru possesses shadow jutsu, Ino has mind controlling jutsu.

The Uzumaki clan is said to have sealing techniques. Then why doesn't Naruto possess any of the techniques? At least, he should have some of his father's abilities (excluding Rasengan, as Jiraiya and Kakashi were able to do it), but from the beginning, it is shown that he didn't possess any clan-specific technique. Why so?

Comment: Like what @JNat is saying, naruto did not receive any training directly through his clan. All the mention name above had their parents training them even sasuke got some training from his dad and brother in the earlier stage.

Comment: Clan power you mean kekkei genkai(bloodline limit)?

Comment: Your idea of Kekkei Genkai is way off base.  As stated above they are bloodline limits.  The clans you listed above do have special techniques that they pass down to their offspring, but those are techniques that can be passed on to anyone.
Kekkei Genkai are abilities that few have, like the First Hokage's ability to combine Earth and water to use the Wood release.  Even though a ninja may be able to use both elements, they cannot use wood release unless it is in their blood.  To elaborate Kekkei genkai are special abilities that cannot be taught.

Comment: What do you expect? Naruto should know sealing techniques from the time he is born?? That's not possible or even sensible in my opinion!

Comment: Like @JNat said Naruto would have been taught this "specific" ninjutsus. Naruto couldn't have just thought himself without even knowing what to do. I mean he couldn't just be born and know what to do already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sub><sup>To expand on my comment, as per [nhahtdh's request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/why-doesnt-naruto-possess-any-of-his-clans-specific-jutsu?noredirect=1#comment26938_19111):</sup></sub>

Because clan specific jutsu **have to be taught**, even though you may have an affinity toward them or less difficulty in learning them.

Unlike [*Kekkei Genkai*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kekkei_Genkai), which are techniques (usually) unique to a clan **passed down genetically**, clan specific jutsu - or [*Hiden*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiden) - are **passed down through teaching/orally**.

**Examples of *Kekkei Genkai*** include, but are not limited to, the Sharingan, the Byakugan, the Shikotsumyaku (Kimimaro's bone ability), Ice Release techniques (used by Haku) and Wood Release techniques.
**Examples of *Hiden*** include, but are not limited to, the Nara clan's Shadow techniques, the Aburame clan's Insect techniques, the Hyuuga clan's fighting style (Gentle Fist) and the Uzumaki clan's Sealing techniques.

However, it is also noteworthy to point out that Naruto possesses many of the [general "abilities" of the Uzumaki clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uzumaki_Clan#Abilities), such as an incredibly strong life force, great recuperative powers and over the average longevity. He possesses these because, not unlike *Kekkei Genkai*, they are passed down genetically. 
On the other hand, he does not posess the clan's specific jutsu, due to the simple fact that **there was no Uzumaki around to teach them to him.**

Comment: Hmmm I think the only power naruto does never show are the chakra chains aside from that he showed every inborn power/trait of the uzumaki clan.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is probably because Naruto is genetically 1/2 Uzumaki and 1/2 another clan (Namikaze). Unlike the other Uzumaki clan members we have seen (Kushina, Karin, Nagato, Mito), Naruto does not have their trademark straight red hair. Instead, he inherits his father's spiky blonde hair. I think this probably results in inheriting only a portion of the Uzumaki genetic characteristics (e.g., compatibility as Kurama's jinchukiri), but losing others (e.g., chakra chains, fuinjutsu).

Answer (score 1):

Naruto does seem to have the innate ability to manipulate the seal on Kurama however, with not indication that he received training on this. So he does have some skill in the art.